# Why the value of b does not change in main function?

Tags: c, function

C program below

```
void test_func(int a, int b, int *c) {
    a ^= 5;
    *c = a + b;
    b <<= 4;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 0x011, c = 0;
    test_func(a, b, &c);
    a = (b > c) ? b : c;
    printf ("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
}
```

The compiler outputs a = 23,b=17 and c = 23 which is not what i expected. I brainstormed step by step in this way :

```
Main function
Function call is made where a = 3 , b = 17(in int), c=0
and values are passed to the test_func 
Functions runs:
a = 3 ^ 5 = 0110 or 6 ; 
c = 17+ 6 = 10100 or 23;
b = 17x2^4 = 272 ; (by the formula of bitwise left shift operator)
Return to the main function
b is definitely greater than c so a returns 272 ;
```

Therefore I expected the result 272,272 and 23 . However the compiler shows 23,17,23. It took me quite a while to realize that b<<=4 never changed the value of b in main function. Please explain why is that so , why didn't the value of b change in main function if values of a and c did?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: you're doing the right thing with `c` that you aren't doing with `b`.

Comment: C passes parameters by *value*, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Function parameter variables are distinct entities from the arguments the function is called with. The parameters are a *copy* of (a potential conversion of) the arguments. (Reference semantics can be implemented by using pointers.)

Comment: Try to name the parameters `x`, `y`, and `z`, and see if that changes the expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, all parameters are pass by value.  That means that changing the value of a function parameter is not reflected in the calling function.

You can however emulate passing by reference by passing the *address* of a variable to a function, as you did with `c`.  When you then dereference the pointer variable in the function, you're changing what `c` in `test_func` points to, i.e. `c` in main.

This is why `b` doesn't change in `main`.  For the same reason, `a` also doesn't change.  `a` does however change on the following line when it is assigned to.

It's also important to note that `a`, `b`, and `c` in `main` are **not** the same as `a`, `b`, and `c` in `test_func`.  You could change the names in either one and it will work the same way.

In order for `a` and `b` to change, you need to pass their addresses, just like you did with `c`.  So change the type of the parameters of your function (and dereference to get the values):

```
void test_func(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
  *a ^= 5;
  *c = *a + *b;
  *b <<= 4;
}
```

Then call it like this, passing in the addresses of `a` and `b`:

```
test_func(&a, &b, &c);
```